# Will boomerang work in vacuum chamber on Earth?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile, vacuum

Earth's gravity, the way we spin and air pressure are essential to have fun with the boomerang. Suppose we do same thing except in a vacuum chamber totally devoid of air will it still be able to "homing"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. A boomerang is an airfoil, and generates a lift force as it travels. Without air, an airfoil is useless.

Comment: ...and hence fly ballistically, like a tennis ball.