# Could an egg theoretically be thrown like a boomerang?

Tags: projectile, aerodynamics

I don't know exactly how boomerangs work, but I imagine that the fact that they are less symmetric than a sphere is part of the reason they can be thrown in such a way that they return to whomever threw them. Eggs also appear to lack some symmetry, because one side is usually pointier than the other. Of course eggs aren't ass aerodynamic as boomerangs and here it is claimed that aerodynamics plays a vital role for how boomerangs work, so probably the answer to my question is no:
[Will boomerang work in vacuum chamber on Earth?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/172010/)

But I am still curious as to what would happen if you did throw an egg (shaped object) really fast like a boomerang. Does anybody know?

Comment: see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/brng.html to understand that the proposition is impossible.

Comment: Egg and football are very similar, so if you don't want to throw eggs why not try it with a football. Even a round ball turning around fast enough will fly a curve.

Comment: @trula An American football has two equally pointy sides, so that wouldn't really be the same as an egg which has one side that is pointier than the other.

Comment: I did not say it is the same, but it will behave very similar the slight difference  of the two ends does not matter .